# How do I schedule a Rule using Fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using the [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules, and I'd like to keep in touch with my clients after they buy things from my store.

I would like to add a `follow_up_date` Field to the Product entity, and use that to schedule Rules.  I've set up the rules, I've used the `Entity has field` condition so that `follow_up_date` gets loaded and can be read from and edited, but it doesn't appear as a data selector for scheduling components.

I've tried using the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) and [Integer Date](http://drupal.org/project/integerdate) modules, and with datestamps of various kinds and granularities, but no dice.

How can I schedule a Rule using data from a Field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the access the product, fx via an order, a Rules bug/flaw is probably what's stopping you, see the [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1053850) on d.o.

There is a work around to fix this by using `hook_entity_property_info_alter`. Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter() on top of the Line Item module.
 */
function module_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  // Add custom discount fields to circumvent a rules bug.
  $properties = array();

  foreach ($info['commerce_product']['bundles'] as $bundle => $bundle_info) {
    $bundle_info += array('properties' => array());
    $properties += $bundle_info['properties'];
  }

  $info['commerce_product']['properties']['field_NAME'] = $properties['field_NAME'];
}
```